# Drupal error "CKEditor is already installed" when trying to install

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor, drupal-modules

I installed CKEditor, but for some reason, when I opened the configuration, Drupal says: "CKEditor not installed."

I deleted the folder from `sites\modules\ckeditor`, then tried to install a different version. On trying to install, it still said "CKEditor is already installed", even though I'd deleted it (and checked it was no longer in the list of modules).

I guess there might be some trouble with the database.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Im idiot. Cause I opened by mistake a different FTP, user and was looking at different folder all/sites/modules.....in this folder I deleted everything, but of course the web I was working on had different module folder :-(. So it kept telling me CKEDITOR was installed why I couldn see it... I ll shoot myself soon. Sorry.